# Is there any recent research on $(2+p)$-SAT?

Tags: satisfiability, research

I've read a few papers (searched by Google Scholar) about $(2+p)$-SAT, but they're all quite old (2001 and earlier). Do newer publications exist? I'm looking for solvers, theorems and so on. I want to examine this topic thoroughly.

Comment: Did you look for papers citing the ones you read?

Comment: Yes, but of course not all of them, I've analyzed the most cited ones.